# 1D Hubbard model in the negative $U$ limit

Tags: condensed-matter

In the 1D Hubbard model at half-filling, is the ground state considered as a charge-density wave (CDW) state in the very negative $U$ limit? Is there a long range order exist in this case? Is a CDW state necessarily conducting?